# How to use toFixed method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to write 2 decimal numbers, I don't know how to use `toFixed` in this case?

```
<head>
<title>Calculate</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function calcform(){
    result.value = (number1.value - 32) / 1.8;
 }
</script>
<body bgcolor="lightgreen">
    <form>
        <p><fieldset><legend>JavaScript</legend></p>
        Fahrenheit degree:
        <input type="text" id="number1" value="" size="10" /><br/>
        <p>
        Celsius degree:
        <input type="text" id="result" value="" size="10" /><br/>
        <p>
        <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calcform()".toFixed(2) />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
        <p></fieldset></p>
        </strong>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? It's pretty easy.

Comment: LMGTFY: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: That HTML is riddled with errors. Use a validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result.value = ((number1.value - 32) / 1.8).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thx. All the time I thought it should be typed somewhere else. And I corrected all mistakes.